# ASP.NET MVC4 - Issue with Rendersection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wurfl

Below are the layout sections used separately for desktop & mobile rendering.
I am facing an issue in production, at some time the body content for mobile sets to desktop. I am suspecting whether it is a problem with rendersection/Same body name used for both layouts/Any other? Any ideas please share. 
Note: Also i am using WURFL for device detection

**Desktop Layout**

```
<div class="wrapper column-one-hundred">
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Header"); }
<div class="container">
@{ 
  Html.RenderPartial("_Error", null);
  Html.RenderPartial("_Session");
 }
 @RenderBody()
 @RenderSection("body")
 </div>
 </div>
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Footer"); }
```

**Mobile Layout**

```
<div id="page" class="c">
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Header.Mobile"); }
@{
Html.RenderPartial("_Error.Mobile", null);
Html.RenderPartial("_Session.Mobile");
}
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("body")
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Footer.Mobile"); }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which WURFL Product, version and wurfl.xml version are you using?

Also, what you posted are the views. Based on your description the issue seems likely to be in the "dispatcher" part, i.e. the part that determines whether an HTTP request originates from a desktop browser or a mobile device.
It will probably also help if you post the user-agent strings of the devices that you find problematic.

Comment: 1.5.1 is the product version i am using.I can't say specific user agents causing the issue. It happens in production as an intermittent issue. Observed more often it is 1.5.1 version. Checked the event logs in the production server:

Comment: Below are the error details from Event viewer throws continuously.Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/SeatMap/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAct>

Comment: Current version of WURFL .NET API is 1.9.5, so you are due for an update. That's the first thing ScientiaMobile support will probably recommend once you contact them. After that, the awesome support team can assist in pinpointing the issue and addressing it.